# Recursive max function for a range in java or python

Tags: java, python, recursion, max

I have this exercise from 'Think java, how to think like a computer scientist.' by Allen B Downey:

> Write a method called `maxInRange` that takes an array of integers
>   and a range of indices (`lowIndex` and `highIndex`), and that finds the
>   maximum value in the array, considering only the elements between
>   `lowIndex` and `highIndex`, including both ends.
>
> This method should be recursive. If the length of the range is `1`, that is,
>   if `lowIndex == highIndex`, we know immediately that the sole element
>   in the range must be the maximum. So that's the base case.
>
> If there is more than one element in the range, we can break the array
>   into two pieces, find the maximum in each of the pieces, and then find
>   the maximum of the maxima.

I have come up with a close but very inaccurate answer in python:

```python
cycles=0

def max_in_range(lst,low,high):

    '''

    Could not be able to make it work correctly

    '''



    global cycles

    cycles+=1

    if low==high:

        #print "Cycles: ",cycles

        return lst

    else:

        max_left=max_in_range(lst[low:len(lst)/2+1],low+1,high)

        max_right=max_in_range(lst[len(lst)/2:len(lst)],low+1,high)

        return max_right if max_right>max_left else max_left



lst=[112,32,45,71238,9999,45,12,6,3]   # always Returns the mid element.

print max_in_range(lst,0,10)



def max(lst):

    global cycles

    cycles+=1

    if len(lst)==1:

        print "Cycles: ",cycles

        return lst[0]

    else:

        m=max(lst[1:])

        return m if m> lst[0] else lst[0]



print max(lst)
```

The `max` function is easy enough compared to what the question requires i.e that the function 
be recursive, take two limits and split the list while running. The `max_in_range` function always 
returns the mid element in the array i.e. `9999`.

I need some pointers on how to satisfy the requirements of the question. In Java or Python or whichever other C-like language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in code.

```py
def max_in_range(lst, low, high):
    # If the length of the range is 1, the sole element in the range must be the maximum.
    if low == high:
        return lst[low]

    # break the array into two pieces, lst[low:low+1] / lst[low+1:high+1],
    # find the maximum in each of the pieces
    piece1_max = lst[low]
    piece2_max = max_in_range(lst, low + 1, high)

    # find the maximum of the maxima
    if piece1_max > piece2_max:
        return piece1_max
    else:
        return piece2_max

lst = [112,32,45,71238,9999,45,12,6,3]
print max_in_range(lst, 0, len(lst) - 1)
```

Comment: Haha, @falsetru, your solution works quite well even though it feels like cheating. I thought when the question said split the list, it meant it should be in the middle. But hey, as long as it works.

Comment: Hi falsetru, is there an advantage in splitting with your method and splitting it in half like the example from Daniel below you.  is your method faster?

Comment: @VasileSurdu, Comparison count of both versions will be same. (Confirm this by adding `print` statement before the comparison or by using some global counter).

Comment: @VasileSurdu, According to call depth, Daniel's version will cause less call depth.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your call to:

```
print max_in_range(lst,0,len(lst))
```

so that you're not overflowing the array as your example does.

But the rest of it should probably look like this:

```
split = low + ((high - low) / 2)

max_left  = max_in_range(lst, low, split - 1)
max_right = max_in_range(lst, split, high)
```